# Calling a virtual function of the base class in a non virtual function of the base class

Tags: c++

Is it correct to call a virtual function of a base class implemented in the derived class in a non-virtual function of the base class. Something like

```
class A
{
 virtual void func1() = 0;

 void func2()
 {
   func1();
 }
};

class B : public A
{
 virtual void func1()
 {
   //do something here;
 }
};

int main()
{
 A* obj = new B;
 obj->func2();
 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This technique is used when you need virtual function behavior for operator implementations: you define your operator in terms of a virtual (or abstract) function and let specializations to decide how that function is implemented.

example:

```
class base
{
// yada yada yada
    base& operator=(const base& other) { return assign(other); }
protected:
    virtual base& assign(const base& other) = 0; // specializations will decide
                                                 //  what assignment means
};
```

Edit: another use for the technique is to allow specializations of your class to control only parts of a more complex operation:

```
class database
{
public:
    void execute(const std::string& query)
    {
        begin_transaction(); // in practice, this should be RAII
        connection_.execute(query);
        end_transaction();
    }
protected:
    virtual void begin_transaction() = 0;
    virtual void end_transaction() = 0;
private:
    whatever &connection_;
};
```

In the database specializations, a hypothetical `mysql_database::begin_transaction` would have a different implementation than `sqlite_database::begin_transaction`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this will work. Did you try it yourself?

Comment: +1. Of course sometimes "try it" leads to things like "y = x++ + x++" - which does "work", but doesn't "work right every time". So just because something works, doesn't mean it's acceptable or even right.

Answer (score 2):

Not only is it a well known and working way to solve things, but if the `func2` is inlined, it probably means that there is no extra overhead compared to doing a direct call to the inside function. Obviously, sometimes the whole purpose is to do some things inside `func1` and then call `func2` in the middle or at the end, but in cases where that extra work is minimal, the "extra function layer" probably disappears completely.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's fine.  This allows you to provide common flow in the base class, the details of  which are specialized in its children.

See [template method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: ok, thanks :) . I was trying something complicated within func1 which was giving me linker errors which i thought was due to implementation fault :)